# Getting all the text content from a HTML string in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, parsing

I need to get only the text content from a HTML String with a space or a line break separating the text content of different elements.

For example, the HTML String might be:

```html
<ul>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
</ul>
```

What I want:

```
First Second
```

or

```
First
Second
```

I've tried to get the text content by first wrapping the entire string inside a `div` and then getting the `textContent` using third party libraries. But, there is no spacing or line breaks between text content of different elements which I specifically require (i.e. I get `FirstSecond` which is not what I want).

The only solution I am thinking of right now is to make a DOM Tree and then apply recursion to get the nodes that contain text, and then append the text of that element to a string with spaces.
Are there any cleaner, neater, and simpler solution than this?

Comment: You can use the package [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) to do these sorts of things, it is built for scraping/navigating/selecting HTML content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Convert HTML to Plain Text:

In your terminal, install the `html-to-text` npm package:

`npm install html-to-text`

Then in **JavaScript**::

```js
const { convert } = require('html-to-text'); // Import the library

var htmlString = `
<ul>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
</ul>
`;

var text = convert(htmlString, { wordwrap: 130 })
// Out:
// First
// Second
```

- Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can try get rid of html tags using regex, for the yours example try the following:

```
let str = `<ul>
<li>First</li>
<li>Second</li>
</ul>`

console.log(str)

let regex = '<\/?!?(li|ul)[^>]*>'

var re = new RegExp(regex, 'g');

str = str.replace(re, '');
console.log(str)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454

Answer (score 1):

Using the DOM, you could use `document.Node.textContent`. However, NodeJs doesn't have textContent (since it doesn't have native access to the DOM), therefore you should use external packages. You could install `request` and `cheerio`, using npm. `cheerio`, suggested by [Jon Church](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5917230/jon-church), is maybe the easiest web scraping tool to use (there are also complexer ones like `jsdom`) 
With power of `cheerio` and `request` in your hands, you could write

```
const request = require("request");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const fs = require("fs");

//taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/19709846/10713877
function is_absolute(url)
{
    var r = new RegExp('^(?:[a-z]+:)?//', 'i');
    return r.test(url);
}

function is_local(url)
{
    var r = new RegExp('^(?:file:)?//', 'i');
    return (r.test(url) || !is_absolute(url));
}

function send_request(URL)
    {
        if(is_local(URL))
        {
            if(URL.slice(0,7)==="file://")
                url_tmp = URL.slice(7,URL.length);
            else
                url_tmp = URL;

           //taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/20665078/10713877
           const $ = cheerio.load(fs.readFileSync(url_tmp));
           //Do something
           console.log($.text())
        }
        else
        {
            var options = {
                url: URL,
                headers: {
                  'User-Agent': 'Your-User-Agent'
                }
              };

            request(options, function(error, response, html) {
                //no error
                if(!error && response.statusCode == 200)
                {
                    console.log("Success");

                    const $ = cheerio.load(html);


                    return Promise.resolve().then(()=> {
                        //Do something
                        console.log($.text())
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    console.log(`Failure: ${error}`);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Let me explain the code. You pass a URL to `send_request` function. It checks whether the URL string is a path to your local file, (a relative path, or a path starting with `file://`). If it is a local file, it proceeds to use `cheerio` module, otherwise, it has to send a request, to the website, using the `request` module, then use `cheerio` module. Regular Expressions are used in `is_absolute` and `is_local`. You get the text using `text()` method provided by `cheerio`. Under the comments `//Do something`, you could do whatever you want with the text.
There are websites that let you know `'Your-User-Agent'`, copy-paste your user agent to that field.

Below lines will work

```
//your local file
send_request("/absolute/path/to/your/local/index.html"); 
send_request("/relative/path/to/your/local/index.html"); 
send_request("file:///absolute/path/to/your/local/index.html"); 
//website
send_request("https://stackoverflow.com/");
```

**EDIT:** I am on a linux system.

Comment: This is helpful but there's a LOT more in here than what is needed to answer the question. If you want to make this answer more useful I'd recommend stripping out everything about using fs/request in node and answer how to turn an html string into the inner text of the nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Okay you can try this example, This may help you

I used `JSDom` module

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const dom = new JSDOM(`<!DOCTYPE html><p>Hello world</p>`);
console.log(dom.window.document.querySelector("p").textContent);
```

BTW Helped me
[image]

This code can help I think :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using npm library `htmlparser2`. Its will be very simple using this

```js
const htmlparser2 = require('htmlparser2');

const htmlString = ''; //your html string goes here
const parser = new htmlparser2.Parser({
    ontext(text) {
      if (text && text.trim().length > 0) {
        //do as you need, you can concatenate or collect as string array
      }
    }
  });

parser.write(htmlString);
parser.end();
```